# Minima of $\sin (1+\sin x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I want to find the minima of $f(x) = \sin (1+ \sin x)$ for $0<x<6$

So a minimum value of $\sin \theta$ occurs at $\frac{3 \pi }{2}$, so I would have thought to set $1+\sin x = \frac{3 \pi}{2}$, but this is not valid.

The answers are two minima at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{3 \pi}{2}$ but I can’t seem to justify them. I can work out the maxima.

I don’t want to use calculus.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: notice that $0\leq 1+\sin x\leq 2 (<\pi)$.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was not attentive.

Comment: The minimum value of $\sin\theta$ occurs at $\color{Red}{\theta=}\frac{3\pi}{2}$...

Comment: $\pi/2$ is only a local minimum; the global minima are at $3\pi/2+2n\pi$. How do you expect to locate local minima without calculus? (I'm not saying it's impossible, I just wonder whether you have thought this through.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$-1\le\sin x\le 1,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$
Thus we know that $0\le\sin x +1\le 2$ therefore
$$\sin (\sin x+1)\ge 0$$
More precisely $\sin (\sin x+1)=0$ at $x=\frac32\pi$ where $\sin x=-1$ and we have the global minimum.

To get the local minimum at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ consider that

- $\sin x$ increases for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and decreases for $\pi>x>\frac{\pi}{2}$
- $\sin  (\sin x+1)$ is decreasing when  $\frac{\pi}{2}<x<2$, reaches a minimum $\sin 2$ when $\sin x = 1$ at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ then increases again up to $1$ when $x=\pi$

Hope it is clear. It's quite complicated to explain  without derivatives  :)

a graph can help

---

$$...$$
[image]

Comment: Did you want to write $0 \leq 1 + \sin(x) \leq 2$ by chance? Because otherwise $0\leq \sin(x)\leq 2$ sounds a bit weird :D

Comment: @Turing Thank you!

Comment: What about the local minimum $\pi/2$?

Comment: @MartinVesely I misread the question. Thought they wanted the global minimum. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $0\leq 1 +\sin x\leq 2$ ($<\pi$). If $0<w<2$, then $\sin w >0$ and if $w=0$, then $\sin w = 0$. Thus the (global) minimum will occur when $1+\sin x =0$, i.e., $\sin x =-1$. Since $0<x<6$, this means $x=\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you do not want to use calculus but it seems to be the only way how to identify all minima:

A first derivative of $f(x)$ is $f'(x) = \cos(x)\cos(1+\sin(x))$. From $f'(x)=0$ we have two equations:

$$
\cos(x) = 0
$$

$$
\cos(1+\sin(x))=0
$$

On given interval the first equation has solution $x \in \{\pi/2; 3\pi/2\}$.

The second one can be turned to $1+\sin(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ since cosinus is zero in $\pi/2$, hence we have either
$$
x = \arcsin(\pi/2-1)
$$
or
$$
x = \pi - \arcsin(\pi/2-1)
$$

You can show that $\pi/2$ adn $3\pi/2\$ are minima and others are maxima.